# AppEngine: sending email to admin, billed as "Recipients Emailed" instead of "Admins Emailed"

Tags: google-app-engine

My apps uses email to notify me about important events. It's doing so (using Python runtime) by sending email to my email address -- marked as owner of the app.

The free tier allows 100 emails per day to receipients, but 5,000 to admins. I expected these notification emails to be billed as "admin" emails.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you use the mail.send_mail_to_admins() method?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/functions

Comment: Thanks. No, I missed that one. I *did* actually expect to find something like that (that treats email-to-admin as a special case), but I only looked at the Mail->Overview page.